# Primefaces: InputText fields VALUES not updating after FileUpload

Tags: java, jsf, file-upload, primefaces

**[SHORT VERSION EXPLANATION]**: I'm having problems updating some `inputText` values after a file upload. It's not working if ANY other `inputText` element has been filled before the upload.

**[LONG VERSION]**: I need help understanding the reason why after uploading a file that changes the `inputText` fields values (in the managedBean), the `inputText` fields don't assume their new values after their element has been updated.

The page is made of a Form, containing 2 fragments:

- The 1st one, has 3 inputText fields - **inputText_A**, **inputText_B** and **inputText_C**;
- The 2nd one contains only a **FileUpload** element. The uploaded file, contains the values used to fill the inputText fields mentioned above;

What I found:

1. `FileUpload` successfully changes updates the managedbeans variables values (category.setName() and category.setValue() is triggered after uploading the file).
2. **IF** I upload the file  **BEFORE** I type anything in inputText_A, **everything works as expected** - the inputText_B and inputText_C values **are** updated
3. **IF** I type anything in inputText_A and then upload the file, then the inputText_B and inputText_C values **are not** updated.
4. In any of those cases the `update="fileUploadField inputTextFields"` is working (getters are called and the fields are disabled after the file has been uploaded)

**NOTE:** The inputText_B and _C need to be inputTexts, because the user should be allowed to input the info manually in case he doesn't have the necessary file.

**fields.xhtml**

```
<p:fieldset id="inputTextFields" toggleable="true" toggleSpeed="150"
        <p:inputText id="inputText_A"
            value="#{uploaded.category.serial}"
            disabled="#{details.disabled()}"
            required="true"
            requiredMessage="#{msg['uploaded.category.serial.empty']}"
            onblur="deactivateCategoryListOrButton(); setChanged()">
        </p:inputText>

        <p:inputTextarea id="inputText_B"
            value="#{uploaded.category.name}"
            disabled="#{details.disabled()}"
            required="true"
            requiredMessage="#{msg['uploaded.category.name.empty']}"
            autoResize="false" rows="4"
            valueChangeListener="#{uploaded.fieldListener}"
            onblur="deactivateCategoryListOrButton(); setChanged()">
        </p:inputTextarea>

        <p:inputTextarea id="inputText_C"
            value="#{uploaded.category.value}"
            disabled="#{details.disabled()}"
            required="true"
            requiredMessage="#{msg['uploaded.category.name.empty']}"
            valueChangeListener="#{uploaded.fieldListener}"
            onblur="deactivateCategoryListOrButton(); setChanged()">
        </p:inputText>
</p:fieldset>
```

**uploader.xhtml**

```
<p:fieldset id="fileUploadField" toggleable="true" toggleSpeed="150"
    <h:panelGroup>
        <p:fileUpload id="#{details.fileUploadCompIdRule}"
            fileUploadListener="#{details.handleFileUpload}"
            mode="advanced" allowTypes="/(\.|\/)(xml)$/"
            label="#{msg['uploaded.category.button.browse']}"
            multiple="false" auto="true"
            update="fileUploadField inputTextFields"
            disabled="#{details.categoryActive()}"
            oncomplete="deactivateCategoryListOrButton(); setChanged()" />
    </h:panelGroup>
</p:fieldset>
```

Thanks in advance!
RMG

Comment: Try using `<p:ajax process="@this" update="@none" />` on input fields.

Comment: it didn't work. I need the update to happen in both input fields right after the upload, with the updated values.

Comment: Why are you using capitalized property names? e.g. `#{uploaded.category.Serial}`, shouldn't it be `#{uploaded.category.serial}`?

Comment: Hey Parkash! Thanks for the reply. That was a typo when editing the variable names to post the question. They're all in lowercase in the project. Thanks for noticing that. I'm editing it now.